# Где поставить запятую

Tags: пунктуация

И снова запятые -_- "Мы сидели в нашем любимом кафе(?) напротив друг друга(?) и не говоря ни слова."
Где поставить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нигде.Правда, мне ещё не нравится корявость "напротив друг друга", лучше бы "друг против друга"

"Мы сидели в нашем любимом кафе напротив друг друга и не говоря ни слова". Запятых нет. Логическое ударение падает не на сказуемое, а на однородные обстоятельства, важно не то, что сидели, а то, что тихо и друг против друга.

Comment: Мне тоже построение не особо нравится, но, к сожалению, переделать нельзя. Спасибо за ответ и разъяснение!

Answer (score 0):

А чем вам не нравится фраза "напротив друг друга"? Вполне нормальная фраза. Грамота тоже признает этот вариант.

НАПРОТИВ. 1. наречие Непосредственно перед кем-чем-нибудь, на противоположной стороне. Он живёт напротив Дом напротив 2. наречие Иначе, наперекор. О чём ни попроси, всё делает напротив 3. вводн. сл. и частица. То же, что наоборот (в 3 и 4 значение). Не груб, напротив, вежлив. Он груб? — Напротив 4. кого-чвго, предлог с род. п. ***Прямо перед кем-чем-нибудь, против (во 2 значение).*** ***Сесть напротив друг друга.*** Жить напротив гостиницы.

[Толковый словарь русского языка***](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=486.LigjhFvLcLGXSXPTzPdbt61SFYtrbYoH3pvHSAxCEfY9nbWovjJEE7H41oo0uuGg8G0YuW8a5hn5QL4OH1v9g_GyUe6y51kicyMKXBKlSTf3zCyDdg0jY9K5Tsl_cxA02B63v1rhMfsX0AJB-oLKifiGDbeIY_V2j-Ue4GyOZxNqojDlTAC2xVSwabZ_P5HZ.8f35644166600c100ae9567f4dea2718d5362138&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9Xukz0dqPN807yUm-tptTKWVX9GYEJiXpJT1lbCO8s5TLngiGSmxc9DPwv8lSbL42nhZzVt3Rq28KQSN_GJhUagdTGjwauZfKvmYIZxb6XJXMny6NZxY5phyhH_ggjnlnPHFQI86qz95lAge8wbWRfjQAd1ylfNsZkrzseVQCfLv2eYNxOYkXnK--1wqzAO4A44rJDttS2c27A&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxbVM5WkZpWDZxTXczRk42ZHFWY3hpbDJBY01EaVQ3M0VmS2p0NldXclpNYmx5LWgxOWRZenMySVFKQTBqa01SRk5fbmlTdjFfS01PUXVDelNLODlQT3ZIR0hOU2dGMFRQQQ&b64e=2&sign=b7ff029a3c3c1774dbf15406a9386aa3&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1414092649671&mc=4.837776924748767***)